# JDialog not Displaying until 'dispose' Executed

Tags: java, joptionpane

I am trying to create a JDialog that will remain open until it is closed and not permit the user to close it.

```
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MessageClass {

    private JDialog waitDialog;

    public MessageClass(String string_,String title_) {

        JOptionPane msg=new JOptionPane(string_,
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
            JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,null,new Object[]{},null);
        waitDialog=msg.createDialog(title_);
    }

    public void openWait() {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                waitMessage();
            }
        });
    }

    private void waitMessage() {
        waitDialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        waitDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(GUI.getInstance().frame);
        waitDialog.setModalityType(ModalityType.DOCUMENT_MODAL);
        waitDialog.pack();
        waitDialog.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void closeWait() {
        waitDialog.dispose();
    }

}
```

I have 3 problems with this class that I cannot understand. The first is that the pane will not display until the dispose is called. The second is that it will not dispose which is probably related to the first problem (I haven't tried calling dispose twice). The third is that the pane does not display the text but rather is blank.

I set up the class like this:

```
MessageClass msg=new MessageClass("Information text","Title");
msg.openWait();
// a bunch of code
msg.closeWait();
```

Can someone spot what I am doing wrong? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you running openWait() and closeWait() ? If they are on the EventDispatchThread, you block that thread until the closeWait() finishes execution, so the dialog does not get a chance to draw itself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As a relative Java novice, I am on shaky ground when it comes to what thread is running when so I am not really sure. I thought 'invokelater' lets things run as separate processes whenever its turn comes up. My 'main' uses 'invokelater' to bring up my main GUI (JFrame). That has a menu item that instantiates a JDialog which itself does an 'invokelater' similar to this class. That JDialog has a code segment that does some network stuff so it can take some time. It instantiates this class, calls 'openWait()' to let the user know what is happening and makes the user wait.

Comment: I should also add that this class stays active even when the application is ended.